# Can anonymous types have no-argument constructors?

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-types

I'm using a library which internally uses Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate objects of a certain type.  The parameter for the function is System.Type, so I was thinking of trying something like this:

```
SomeFunction(new { SomeStringProperty = "" }.GetType());
```

It looks like this particular anonymous type has a constructor that takes a string - to assign the property immediately.  I have ways to work around this problem but now I'm curious - is there a way to have the anonymous type have a no-arg constructor so that it can be used in situations where CreateInstance is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot affect the generated constructor(s) of anonymous types. They're not even something whose existence you should rely on, via reflection or anything else, as anything not specified in the spec for anonymous types is an implementation detail.

This is precisely to prevent people from using them for things they are not intended for, where a proper class should be used.